# Possible to simplify SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, simplify

This querys purpose is to count each unique id (LUID_NO) for four different variants of the "same" type of item.
It works as expected. 
Now to my question, can this query be simplified or written in another way? 
When I look at it,  I can't shake the feeling that it would probably be possible to write it in another much more simple way.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ICL.LUID_NO) 
             FROM       L2000.ITEM_CARRIER IC
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION IUD ON IUD.PV_ID=IC.PV_ID AND IUD.STORER_ID=IC.STORER_ID AND IUD.ITEM_ID=IC.ITEM_ID
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_CARRIER_LUID ICL ON ICL.ITEM_CARRIER_NO=IC.ITEM_CARRIER_NO
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_PROPERTY IP ON IC.PROPERTY_INDEX=IP.PROPERTY_INDEX
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM I ON I.ITEM_ID = IC.ITEM_ID AND I.STORER_ID = IC.STORER_ID
                   WHERE     IC.PV_ID = 'B2' 
                   AND       IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NULL 
                   AND       IUD.UOM_QTY = ICL.PHYSIC_QTY 
                   AND       IUD.UNIT_DEF_ID = 'LU' 
                   AND       IC.STORER_ID = 'PG' 
                   AND       ICL.PHYSIC_QTY > 0  
                   AND       I.ITEM_DESC LIKE '#%' 
                   AND       I.ITEM_GROUP_ID IN ('BABYCARE','FEMCARE')
    )AS B2_PALLETS,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ICL.LUID_NO) 
             FROM       L2000.ITEM_CARRIER IC
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION IUD ON IUD.PV_ID=IC.PV_ID AND IUD.STORER_ID=IC.STORER_ID AND IUD.ITEM_ID=IC.ITEM_ID
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_CARRIER_LUID ICL ON ICL.ITEM_CARRIER_NO=IC.ITEM_CARRIER_NO
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_PROPERTY IP ON IC.PROPERTY_INDEX=IP.PROPERTY_INDEX
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM I ON I.ITEM_ID = IC.ITEM_ID AND I.STORER_ID = IC.STORER_ID
                   WHERE    IC.PV_ID = 'B3' 
                   AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NULL 
                   AND      IUD.UOM_QTY = ICL.PHYSIC_QTY 
                   AND      IUD.UNIT_DEF_ID = 'LU' 
                   AND      IC.STORER_ID = 'PG' 
                   AND      ICL.PHYSIC_QTY > 0 
                   AND      I.ITEM_DESC LIKE '#%' 
                   AND      I.ITEM_GROUP_ID IN ('BABYCARE','FEMCARE')
    )AS B3_PALLETS,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ICL.LUID_NO) 
             FROM       L2000.ITEM_CARRIER IC
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION IUD ON IUD.PV_ID=IC.PV_ID AND IUD.STORER_ID=IC.STORER_ID AND IUD.ITEM_ID=IC.ITEM_ID
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_CARRIER_LUID ICL ON ICL.ITEM_CARRIER_NO=IC.ITEM_CARRIER_NO
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_PROPERTY IP ON IC.PROPERTY_INDEX=IP.PROPERTY_INDEX
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM I ON I.ITEM_ID = IC.ITEM_ID AND I.STORER_ID = IC.STORER_ID
                   WHERE    IC.PV_ID = 'B2' 
                   AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL 
                   AND      IUD.UNIT_DEF_ID = 'LU' 
                   AND      IC.STORER_ID = 'PG' 
                   AND      ICL.PHYSIC_QTY > 0 
                   AND      I.ITEM_DESC LIKE '#%' 
                   AND      I.ITEM_GROUP_ID IN ('BABYCARE','FEMCARE')
    )AS BLOCKED_B2_PALLETS,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ICL.LUID_NO) 
             FROM       L2000.ITEM_CARRIER IC
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION IUD ON IUD.PV_ID=IC.PV_ID AND IUD.STORER_ID=IC.STORER_ID AND IUD.ITEM_ID=IC.ITEM_ID
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_CARRIER_LUID ICL ON ICL.ITEM_CARRIER_NO=IC.ITEM_CARRIER_NO
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_PROPERTY IP ON IC.PROPERTY_INDEX=IP.PROPERTY_INDEX
             INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM I ON I.ITEM_ID = IC.ITEM_ID AND I.STORER_ID = IC.STORER_ID
                   WHERE    IC.PV_ID = 'B3' 
                   AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL 
                   AND      IUD.UNIT_DEF_ID = 'LU' 
                   AND      IC.STORER_ID = 'PG' 
                   AND      ICL.PHYSIC_QTY > 0
                   AND      I.ITEM_DESC LIKE '#%' 
                   AND      I.ITEM_GROUP_ID IN ('BABYCARE','FEMCARE')
    )AS BLOCKED_B3_PALLETS

FROM   L2000.ITEM_CARRIER
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Skip the sub-queries, do a left join instead. And use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Your subqueries are not related to the main query, so instead of `FROM L2000.ITEM_CARRIER WHERE ROWNUM = 1` you can just as well put `FROM DUAL` to start with.

Comment: You join `ITEM` and `ITEM_CARRIER` and `ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION` on `ITEM_ID`. Why not `ITEM_PROPERTY`, too? Doesn't that table have an `ITEM_ID`? It would help if you showed and explained how the tables are related. What is a `PV_ID` for instance?

Comment: What you are looking for is conditional aggregation, as shown in Radim's answer, but there may be more things to fix. You only want results for certain items for instance, so I'd use an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause for `ITEM` rather than joining the table. This is mere criteria and criteria belongs in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks everyone, great tips!

Comment: Thorsten; `PROPERTY_INDEX` is the primary key in `ITEM_PROPERTY` There is no `ITEM_ID` im that table.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IC.PV_ID = 'B2' 
               AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NULL THEN ICL.LUID_NO END) AS B2_PALLETS,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IC.PV_ID = 'B3' 
               AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NULL THEN ICL.LUID_NO END) AS B3_PALLETS,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IC.PV_ID = 'B2' 
               AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN ICL.LUID_NO END) AS BLOCKED_B2_PALLETS,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IC.PV_ID = 'B3' 
               AND      IP.BLOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN ICL.LUID_NO END) AS BLOCKED_B3_PALLETS
         FROM       L2000.ITEM_CARRIER IC
         INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_UNITS_DEFINITION IUD ON IUD.PV_ID=IC.PV_ID AND IUD.STORER_ID=IC.STORER_ID AND IUD.ITEM_ID=IC.ITEM_ID
         INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_CARRIER_LUID ICL ON ICL.ITEM_CARRIER_NO=IC.ITEM_CARRIER_NO
         INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM_PROPERTY IP ON IC.PROPERTY_INDEX=IP.PROPERTY_INDEX
         INNER JOIN L2000.ITEM I ON I.ITEM_ID = IC.ITEM_ID AND I.STORER_ID = IC.STORER_ID
               WHERE    IUD.UOM_QTY = ICL.PHYSIC_QTY 
               AND      IUD.UNIT_DEF_ID = 'LU' 
               AND      IC.STORER_ID = 'PG' 
               AND      ICL.PHYSIC_QTY > 0 
               AND      I.ITEM_DESC LIKE '#%' 
               AND      I.ITEM_GROUP_ID IN ('BABYCARE','FEMCARE')
```

Comment: This looks about right, I do get a "missing expression" running it, though. Can't seem to find the error which I guess is an extra comma or something similar?

Comment: @ChristofferTrabjerg I had an extra comma. Try it now.

Comment: Worked great, I did find the comma also. Thanks!!